# ZSH autocompletion gives seemingly random errors after some time

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

My zsh autocompletion is broken in a strange way. For clean logins everything works but after some time I will get seemingly random autocompletion errors, for different "kinds" of autocompletion. Sometimes `ls foo<tab>` works but `rm foo<tab>` won't. I am completely lost on how to debug this.

I could not find a pattern to a particular command causing it. Neither could I see a pattern on what completion works and what doesn't. In my routine I use gnu modules, run make, compilers, nano etc..

The errors I get upon autocompletion look like this:

```
/bin/zsh:4: _main_complete: function definition file not found
```

or

```
(eval):1: _autocd: function definition file not found
(eval):1: _autocd: function definition file not found
(eval):1: _autocd: function definition file not found
_main_complete:173: _ignored: function definition file not found
_main_complete:173: _ignored: function definition file not found
_main_complete:173: _ignored: function definition file not found
```

or

```
(eval):1: _rm: function definition file not found
(eval):1: _rm: function definition file not found
(eval):1: _rm: function definition file not found
```

I have seen similar messages for _sudo and _module.

I am using zsh (5.0.2) with oh-my-zsh in multiple screen sessions on a machine whose home filesystem is on nfs. I attach to the screen sessions automatically on each login with `screen -xrR` in `.zprofile`

Two files $HOME/.zcompdump and $HOME/.zompdump-`hostname`-5.0.2 are created whenever i login. Removing them made no difference.

Comment: Does the problem appear only the first time you use completion in a shell instance, or does it sometimes appear later as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a consequence of running some code that clobbers the variable `FPATH` or `fpath`. Check the value of either of these variables; it should be a list of directories where zsh loads functions.

The variables `FPATH` and `fpath` are tied (like `PATH` and `path`): changing one affects the other. The uppercase `FPATH` is a string which contains a colon-separated list of directories. The lowercase `fpath` is an array of directories.

Check your startup scripts for any place where you might use either of these names as variables. Check the list of variable names [set](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) or [used](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell) by zsh (`man zshparam`) and make sure you don't use any for different purposes.

Completion functions are autoloaded, i.e. loaded the first time they are used. Once you've done any completion in a shell instance, for example, you should no longer see `_main_complete: function definition file not found` — if `_main_complete` works but then stops working with this message, something weirder is going on.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. You were right. Some modules on the system were setting FPATH, presumably someone thought that if CPATH is for C includes, FPATH must be the version for fortran...